# /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings - create meeting with application token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a proxy application that would create for every user365 the onlinemeeting,
So I have read this:
[documentation update in march](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy)

and it seems that for each user in azure, I have to run a powershell command to allow my application to generate a meeting.

in the example there is this policy with 3 parameter (in the doc explain two parameter) so I'm so confuse:

---

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Test-policy -AppIds "ddb80e06-92f3-4978-bc22-a0eee85e6a9e", "ccb80e06-92f3-4978-bc22-a0eee85e6a9e", "bbb80e06-92f3-4978-bc22-a0eee85e6a9e" -Description "description here"

---

It seems that a policy needs to be created first....
And then the policy has to be associated with each user... one at a time....
Isn't there something global for all users?

Let me explain better: once the application type permissions are activated on

- OnlineMeetings.Read.All OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All

why do I need to do anything else?

In other API (like create calendar event for example [here](http:///users/%7Bid%20%7C%20userPrincipalName%7D/calendar/events)) the policy rule is not necessary... but is necessary only the permission API

Comment: I have found -Global parameter in Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName "ASimplePolicy" -Global !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solve:

There are a -Global parameter that When you use this cmdlet without specifying a user identity, the policy applies to all users in your tenant, except any that have an explicit policy assignment. To skip a warning when you do this operation, specify this parameter.

Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName "ASimplePolicy" -Global